# Can't handle input "change" event or value after document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs on my form whose value I would like to change when the document has loaded.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$base = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
include($base."/include/db.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>eMail Stationery | Installation for iPhone/iPad</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../css/plugins/steps/jquery.steps.2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="gray-bg">

    <div class="">
        <center>
            <img src="../img/esignia.png">
            <h3>iPhone/iPad Installation</h3>

            <p>Follow the steps provided to install your signature</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div id="wizard">
        <h3>Enter your details</h3>
        <section>
            <center>
                <div class="row"></div>
                <p><h2>Enter your details</h2></p>
                <p>Enter your email address and unique pin number into the fields below to receive an email with a link to your signature.</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <form id="submitForm" method="post">
                            <center>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="pin" name="pin" type="number" placeholder="Unique PIN" class="form-control" required>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                <p>

                                </p>
                            </center>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </section>
        <h3>Copying your signature</h3>
        <section>
            <center>
                <p><h2>Copying your signature</h2></p>
                <p>Once you have followed the link we provided in the email, you will see your signature displayed fully on your device's web browser.</p>
                <p>Simply highlight all of your signature and copy it to your device's clipboard as demonstrated below.</p>
                <p><img src="../img/install/iphone_2.png" width="320px" height="480px"></p>
            </center>
        </section>
        <h3>Locating your signature settings</h3>
        <section>
            <center>
                <p><h2>Locating your signature settings</h2></p>
                <p>Great! We've copied your signature and it is now ready to be installed!</p>
                <p>We just need to find your mail's signature settings.</p>
                <p>These are located at <b>Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Signature</b>
                    <p><img src="../img/install/iphone_3.png" width="320px" height="480px">
                        <img src="../img/install/iphone_4.png" width="320px" height="480px"></p>
                    </center>
                </section>
                <h3>Installing your signature</h3>
                <section>
                    <center>
                        <p><h2>Installing your signature</h2></p>
                        <p>Now that we have your signature settings open, you'll find an empty box ready for your signature to be pasted.</p>
                        <p>So all you need to do now is paste what we copied earlier into the box.</p>
                        <p><img src="../img/install/iphone_5.png" width="320px" height="480px"></p>
                        <p>One final thing you'll need to do is give your phone a quick shake to undo any of the modifications that your device will attempt to make to your signature's HTML code.</p>
                        <p>This is necessary for your signature to appear <i>exactly</i> how it appeared when you opened it.</p>
                        <p><img src="../img/install/iphone.gif"></p>
                        <p class="text-navy"><b>Congratulations, you've now successfully installed your signature to your device!</b></p>
                    </center>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mainly scripts -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/plugins/steps/jquery.steps.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var email = getUrlParameter("email");
            var pin = getUrlParameter("pin");
            if(email != undefined && pin != undefined) {
                $("#email").val(email);
                $("#pin").val(pin);
            }
            $("#wizard").steps({
                headerTag: "h3",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                autoFocus: true
            });
            $("#submitForm").submit(function() {
                var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
                var pin = $("input[name='pin']").val();
                $.get("../api/installed.php", {
                    email: email,
                    pin: pin
                });
            });
            $("a[href='#finish'").click(function() {
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            });
        });
        var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
                var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

                for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }
            };
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This does not work.

However, I replicate the same code in chrome's console and it works perfectly. My only assumption is that these controls are being messed with and/or recreated with Bootstrap/jQuery after the document has been loaded.

But I can't figure out where or why, or what I should do.

Comment: What you have should work fine - aside from the missing `)` on the document ready handler, although I assume that's just a typo in the question. Have you checked that `email` and `pin` are set correctly? Any errors in the console? Are you sure the `#email` and `#pin` elements are available in the DOM when the page loads? Can you show an example of the problem?

Comment: I've updated it with the entire code. Have a look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might because of DOM not ready, try using below code

```
$(window).load(function() {
            var email = getUrlParameter("email");
            var pin = getUrlParameter("pin");
            if(email != undefined && pin != undefined) {
                $("#email").val(email);
                $("#pin").val(pin);
            }
        }
```

If still not work try to change your Ids of element to check weather its conflict with other element or not

Comment: That seemed to work. But my code should also work? Makes no sense.